# Run-time error 5981, Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I'm trying to create scripts in Excel and Word that create Word documents from rows in Excel. I'm basing the Word Documents from a 'dotm' template. Everything was working fine (and still does) with the 'dotx' file format, but as soon as I use the Macro-Enabled, I get the 5981 run-time error application-defined or object-defined error.

*I've done research online and tried all fixes from enabling Macros, Trusted Locations and Trusted Documents in Word. I've tried DoEvent before trying to access. I need to access the 'dotm' file as there are Macros in Word I need to run on opening to format the document*.

Can someone *PLEASE* help me? I'm not experienced in VBA and I'm reaching the end of my thread with this.

```
    Set objword = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

        If objword Is Nothing Then
            Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set objDoc = objword.Documents.Add("C:\Users\OMITTED FOR PRIVACY\Test Report.dotm")
```

Results ... 
Expected: Word Documents created and formatted
Actual: Run-time error '5981': Application-defined or object-defined error

*Updated*
Code from the `Test Report.dotm` file:

```
Sub conditionalFormat()

    Dim oCell As Word.Cell
    Dim oColumn As Word.Column

    'First set of tables
    For intI = 2 To 5
        Set oColumn = ActiveDocument.Tables(intI).Range.Columns(3)

        For Each oCell In oColumn.Cells

            If IsNumeric(Left(oCell.Range.Text, Len(oCell.Range.Text) - 2)) Then

                If Val(oCell.Range.Text) < 55 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                ElseIf Val(oCell.Range.Text) > 55 And Val(oCell.Range.Text) < 75 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorLightOrange
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                ElseIf Val(oCell.Range.Text) > 75 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorSeaGreen
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                End If
            End If

        Next
    Next intI

    'Analysis set of tables
    For intI = 8 To 28 Step 3
        Set oColumn = ActiveDocument.Tables(intI).Range.Columns(4)

        For Each oCell In oColumn.Cells

            If IsNumeric(Left(oCell.Range.Text, Len(oCell.Range.Text) - 2)) Then

                If Val(oCell.Range.Text) < 33.3 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                ElseIf Val(oCell.Range.Text) > 33.3 And Val(oCell.Range.Text) < 66.6 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorLightOrange
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                ElseIf Val(oCell.Range.Text) > 66.6 Then
                    oCell.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorSeaGreen
                    oCell.Range.Font.TextColor = wdColorWhite
                    oCell.Range.Font.Bold = True
                    oCell.Range.InsertAfter Text:="%"
                End If
            End If

        Next
    Next intI

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this looks like there is an error in the template macros or the marco file is not trusted. If you open the template file `.dotm` manually (double click the file) what happens? Does it open in *protected view* or does it say *macros disabled*? Do the macros run then? Please check.

Comment: I've deleted and re-saved the `.dotm` file, which doesn't resolve anything. When I open the file, it's fine, doesn't open in protected view and also doesn't disable the macros. I've specifically added the folder to the **trusted locations** list. I've also enabled all macros to be run and nothing seems to work :'(

Comment: To test if this is a code related issue or general macro issue test the following: Create a brand new file `Hello World.dotm` and add the following code in the `Document_Open()` event: `MsgBox "I run fine"`. Then test this file with your code. If you get the same error this is a general macro issue (like trusting) if it shows the message box then there is an issue within the code of your report file.

Comment: I've tested and it seems to work fine, so it must be an issue with the code in the report file. I've updated my original code with the code from my report file. Are you able to tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Try to change `ActiveDocument` into `ThisDocument` (it occurs twice). Note that `Val(oCell.Range.Text) < 33.3` doesn't make much sense because `Val` returns an integer that has no decimals. Eg `Val(33.3)` returns `33`.

Comment: Thank you very much `PEH` your solution has fixed my problem. It does as it should now. If you would like to submit as an answer and I'll accept it as the answer :)

Comment: I added an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ActiveDocument` into `ThisDocument`.

- `ActiveDocument` is the document that has the focus (which can be any document a user clicks on).
- `ThisDocument` is the document this code is running in.